# TabPages for newly opened Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a new tab page for every newly opened form.

Example:

```
frmReport reportform = new frmReport();
report.Show();
```

When I open the `frmReport` form, it must be opened in a new `TabPage`, as in Windows Internet Explorer 7-8 tabpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used DevExpress Controls for tabPages.

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to achive here is to have "windows inside tab pages". This is not like it supposed to be! It looks like this:

- Windows OS
- Windows of applications (Window class)
- Containers placed on Window (for example: Panel, TabControl!)
- Controls placed on Windows and Containers (for example: Button, but also containers like Panel!)

So when you look on this you see that it's not ok to put Windows class into TabControl!

So what to do?

Create for example UserControl class and move all your controls from Window to this new UserControl. Next place on your Window TabControl nad on one of it's TabPages put this newly created UserControl.

In this way you'll have a good designed UI. Once again: You do not put Window on your TabPage!

Comment: can ya gimme an example or how to do it Article ?

Comment: Here you have discussion about this with some code, hope if helps:
http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/270457-can-i-add-form-tabpage

Answer (score 1):

In fact U can add `Windows.Forms` to `TabPages` you just need to do set

```
Form.TopLevel = false
```

and you can add it to any container be it `TabPage` or `Panel`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no direct way to do it. Better to go with Usercontrols instead of Forms and Add controls to the Tab Page.

See [this link](http://k-mug.org/forums/p/360/1200.aspx).